# Как передать параметр из input в качестве ссылки src в iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, input

Добрый день.
У меня есть несколько input вида -

```
<input type="radio" name="TCselect" value="%link%">
```

и есть iframe в который я хочу данную ссылку передать.Результат необходимо чтобы выглядел вот так

```
<iframe id="TCframe" src="%link%"></iframe>
```

Прошу вашей помощи, т.к. с javascript пока на вы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Старайтесь разбираться самостоятельно или так и останетесь с javascript на вы.

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('TCframe');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    iframe.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('value'));
  });
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="TCselect" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yzuT_amWb_s?origin=http://ru.stackoverflow.com"> Привет, я кот<br>
<input type="radio" name="TCselect" value="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZbM6WbUw7Bs?origin=http://ru.stackoverflow.com"> Japanese Donald Trump Commercial<br>
<iframe id="TCframe" src=""></iframe>
```